# How to add features in toolbox of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How am I going to add features in the toolbox? In my toolbox does not have the "PictureBox" and "OpenFileDialog" features. In my system needs to upload pictures but there is only "Image" feature and I dont have any idea to match the codes. Please help me if there are ways for me to upload the pictures. Im using VBnet and SQL server.

Comment: Do you mean for ASP.NET Web Forms, WinForms, or another technology?

Answer (score 0):

That would be because those are Windows Forms controls and the IDE you have is for web development. You need the one for Windows development if you want to develop for Windows. If you want to develop for the web then you have to use controls that are intended for the web.

If you can, I'd suggest ditching VS Express and VS 2012 and install VS 2019 Community. It has all the latest language, framework and IDE features and it has pretty much all the functionality of Professional while still being free.

Comment: im using company desktop so i need permission in installing any software. Do you know any features in visual studio 2012 that similar with "Openfiledialog" and "PictureBox". Or do you have any suggestions on how to upload pictures?

Comment: That's way too broad a question for SO. If you're doing web development, you need to research how to do web development.

Comment: if you create a asp.net webforms project, then you have the toolbox and the familer options. You can continue to use vs2012. So, try creating a asp.net web forms and NOT a MVC project. Asp.net webforms are considered legacy now, but for starting out, it can still be a great choice if you need to cook up something in a hurry and with great ease. MVC has no GUI forms designer, and no toolbox of the asp.net controls say like gridview and especially the listview control.